# Sync UITableViewCell with Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, uitableview

I have some objects stored with Core Data. For example, people. I sync these people with my webservice (XML) and i use NSFetchedResultsController to display people in a UITableView.

Everything works fine and my sync methods run in a background thread (the sync methods are only called once in viewDidLoad).

Now i would like to show a UISwitch in a UITableViewCell. This switch should change a bool value in a person object. Also, I need to display a small toolbar with some icons. If person is x then show y icon, if person is a then show b icon...

Does anyone have any good ideas or examples to implement this?

My first approach:
Subclassing and setting the Core Data object with a method + UISwitch as subview in contentview... I also need to implement the layoutSubviews method.

I wouldn't like to build a .nib file! I need to reuse all parts of the cell in other cells...

But I'm not sure if this is the best way...

Answer (score 0):

Hi
I was out of this way. Fetched result controller have to do this work for u. 
Just connect u BOOL core data state to u uiswitch and make something like:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    [tableView beginUpdates];


    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        {
            NSIndexPath *newIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:2];

            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        {
            NSIndexPath *newIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:2];

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        {
            NSIndexPath *newIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:2];

            [self configureCell:(CompanyAndUserInfoCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndex] atIndexPath:newIndex forTableView:tableView];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        {
            NSIndexPath *newIndexStart = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:2];
            NSIndexPath *newIndexStop = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:2];

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexStart] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexStop] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
    }
    [tableView endUpdates];


}
```